# Pandas multiple conditions for delete some row, condition contains NaT

Tags: python, pandas

My code is as follows:

```
Summary = Summary.drop(Summary[(Summary['Story_opendate'] < sixmonthearly) & 
                               (**Summary['lastEditedDate'] == ""**) & 
                               (Summary['Task_lasteditdate' ] < twomonthearly)].index)
```

I want to delete certain rows according to 3 conditions. I used the drop method but one condition contain Nat value (bold part here) or null as showed in exported excel file.
Then drop method seem can not discern this part and delete rows with these 3 conditions.

I have tried below expression to replace bold part:

```
Summary['lastEditedDate']=="NaN"
Summary['lastEditedDate']=="NaT"
np.where(Summary['lastEditedDate'].values=='NaT'
```

But all in vain.

Please help on this.
Thanks in advance~

Comment: can you make a bit clearer what rows you want to drop? If you do that I'll provide with an answer below.

Comment: I want to drop rows with 3 conditions at same time:
1.Summary['Story_opendate']<sixmonthearly) 
2.(Summary['lastEditedDate']=="") 
3.(Summary['Task_lasteditdate']<twomonthearly)
the second one can not work.
I've find a solution:
    Summary = Summary.drop(Summary[(Summary['Story_opendate']<sixmonthearly) & (Summary.lastEditedDate.isnull()) & (Summary['Task_lasteditdate']<twomonthearly)].index)

Comment: Can you write the conditions clearly? for example remove ```np.nan```, and values that are "".

Comment: Please post your code and data set so that others can reproduce and help answer.  If the data set is too large show a subset.  If you solve your problem please post as an answer.